# Phonegap web-based app "Alert" is showing the name of the page

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have a web app for iPhone, and I use the `UIWebView` option through PhoneGap.

When alerting it shows the name of the html page:
[image]
How can I hide it (`login.html`)?

I use the `alert` function with `JavaScript`:

```
alert("Email and Password do not match.");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes in ios phonegap pages will show the page name in alert. You need to use notification plugin to avoid that.

Here is the plugin

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification

You only need the dialog plugin, not the vibration

```
 cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

To use it, you need

```
 navigator.notification.alert(
        'You are the winner!',  // message
        alertDismissed,         // callback
        'Game Over',            // title
        'Done'                  // buttonName
    );
```